# Data Intent : Pathpattern

Tags: android

On my application I am trying to make it so that it opens a activity when someone clicks a link on the browser. I am using this data block but it wont work.

```
<data android:scheme="http"
      android:host="www.test.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/get/"
      android:pathPattern="/.*\\" />
```

For example when I click on www.test.com it opens the app when it should only open it when the pathPrefix is /get/. How can I fix this?

API: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the prefix as /get but from my understanding of the documentation this is checked against the beginning of the string so it's irrelevant here.

Why it's catching all is this because your regex catches all?

Try something like:

```
 android:pathPattern="[get]"
```

Comment: how about if its something like  /?a=(.*) how can I make that open only